# Which one to choose between "drm_display_mode" and "display_timing" structures in panel-simple.c linux driver?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, display

In the `panel-simple.c` linux display driver (`drivers/gpu/drm/panel/panel-simple.c`) there are two structures that can be used to descrive the display features. These structures are:

- `drm_display_mode`
- `display_timing`

Can be used only one of the two. My question is: when choose `drm_display_mode` and when choose `display_timing`?